# Difficulty with jQuery Autocomplete on a Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm absolutely stumped and have tried as many different iterations as I can find on this issue and would appreciate some help. I have a dynamic table that has a button to add rows, but I cannot get the autocomplete feature to work past the first row. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
var roomNames = [
  "Balcony",
  "Kitchen",
  "Bedroom 1"
];

$( "#room-list" ).autocomplete({
  source: roomNames
});

var Rcounter = 1;

$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    var rowCount = $('#myTable >tbody >tr').length;
    if (rowCount < 24) {

        var $newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        Rcounter++;

        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="room-list" name="room' + Rcounter +'"></td>';

        $newRow.append(cols);
        $newRow.appendTo("table#myTable").autocomplete(roomNames);


    }
});
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding `autocomplete` to the table row. You need to add it to the `input` instead. Also you need to set the `source` for autocomplete as you do for `room-list`. Right now you're only passing in the array.

So something like this should fix it (you could also create the input element separately instead of using `find`):

```
$newRow.find("input").autocomplete({ source: roomNames });
```

Another solution would be to have it set to the table based on a selector instead of setting it to each input. (This will be outside the click event)

e.g.

```
$("#myTable").on('keydown.autocomplete', "input", function() {
  $(this).autocomplete({
    source: roomNames
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent all day today scratching my head begrudgingly wanting to solve this myself. I'm not sure why I don't use this resource more often.

**The solution:**
`newRow.appendTo("table#myTable");
newRow.find("input").autocomplete({source: roomNames});`